# Oracle SQL: Using same alias In CASE statement to select in one case one column, in the other two columns and another three with the same alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing something wrong in a select with cases in Oracle and I'll appreciate the help from the stackoverflow community.

What I am trying to do is based on a condition (value of a column) to return one or multiple columns.

I always need my query to return three columns:
Article, Paragraph, Sub_Paragraph

If the value of a column list_value which I am checking is Article, then I only need to return the Article and null to both Paragraph and Sub Paragraph.
If the value of a column is Paragraph, I need to return both paragraph and article and the Sub_Paragraph should be null.
If the value of a column is Sub_Paragraph, I need to return all values for article, paragraph and Sub_Paragraph.

```
SELECT

     CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Sub_Paragraph' THEN att.column_with_subpar_value
     END AS sub_paragraph,
     CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Sub_Paragraph' THEN att.column_with_par_value
     END AS paragraph,
     CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Sub_Paragraph' THEN att.column_with_article_value
     END AS article,
   
     CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN att.column_with_par_value
     END AS paragraph,
     CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN att.column_with_article_value
     END AS article,
  
     CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Article' THEN att.column_with_article_value
     END AS article
  
 FROM
     att
     
 WHERE
     id = 1
```

but with this approach I am getting column like article_1  , article_2  etc.
What's the best way to succeed it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your requirement, hope below is what you are expecting.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Sub_Paragraph' THEN
          att.column_with_subpar_value
       END AS sub_paragraph,
       CASE
         WHEN att.list_value in ('Sub_Paragraph', 'Paragraph') THEN
          att.column_with_par_value
       END AS paragraph,
       CASE
         WHEN att.list_value in ('Sub_Paragraph', 'Paragraph', 'Article') THEN
          att.column_with_article_value
       END AS article
  FROM att
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: That's a valid answer on what I wrote in my question, thank you. The only problem I have which wasn't clear in my original question is that in the case of Paragraph the value of the Article is from another column (sub select) and same in the case of Sub Paragraph for Paragraph and Article.
Do you have any suggestion for that case?

Comment: Can you provide the sample data as well. So that can help you according to your requirement. Ask it as a new question and provide the link over here. Will help you on that

Comment: I will try to do it, but in fact it's what I have in the main question, just replace CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN att.column_with_article_value
     END AS article with  CASE
         WHEN att.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN (
             SELECT
                 something
             FROM
                 another_table
             WHERE
                 att.id = other.id
         )
     END AS article
I don't know if that helps at all ?

Comment: Yes its possible, if you could provide detailed description along with table structure, will be more efficient to answer you. Please create a new question and let me know, will help you

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797180/oracle-return-same-alias-for-different-cases-on-select
I tried to simplify the question and asking only about article and paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches on how this can be resolved would be to concatenate all the columns into one column with a known separator, which can be split later into the desired set of columns.