# Oracle return same alias for different cases on select

Tags: sql, oracle

What I am trying to do is based on a condition (value of a column) to return one or multiple columns.

I always need my query to return two columns: Article, Paragraph

If the value of a column list_value which I am checking is Article, then I only need to return the Article and null to Paragraph.

If the value of a column is Paragraph, I need to return both paragraph and article but the article's value now returns from a subquery based on the parent column value.

**Table pro_table, Data:**

[image]

```
SELECT
     tbl.parent,
     list.list_value,
     tbl.values_column,
     CASE
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Article' THEN tbl.values_column
     END AS article,
     CASE
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN tbl.values_column
     END AS paragraph,
     CASE
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN (
             SELECT
                 values_column
             FROM
                 pro_table
             WHERE
                 pro_table.id_pro_table = tbl.parent
         )
     END AS article
 FROM
     pro_table tbl 
     LEFT JOIN list ON list.id_list = tbl.id_t_list
```

Comment: Please provide the data of both pro_table and list table. And also provide your expected result

Comment: List table is not important, it's just contains the id and the text of the  list_value

Comment: In your sub query, you are again taking the column from the same table `values_column from pro_table`. There is no need of having a sub query

Comment: Probably, provide your expected result as same as the way you provided pro_table data. Will check and provide you the result

Comment: @WilliamBird - please provide your tables and expected results as formatted text, not as images. Also, the image you have now doesn't show the `id_pro_table` column so we can't see the parent-child link; and is 23006 supposed to be duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your subquery already gets the correct value back, and you're just asking how to get both 'article' values in the same column, all you need to do is move the subquery into a second `when` check within the first `case` expression, instead of as its own column:

```
SELECT
     tbl.parent,
     list.list_value,
     tbl.values_column,
     CASE
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Article' THEN tbl.values_column
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN (
             SELECT
                 values_column
             FROM
                 pro_table
             WHERE
                 pro_table.id_pro_table = tbl.parent
         )
     END AS article,
     CASE
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN tbl.values_column
     END AS paragraph
 FROM
     pro_table tbl 
     LEFT JOIN list ON list.id_list = tbl.id_t_list
```

You could replace the subquery with a left join back to the same table and coalesce the results:

```
SELECT
     tbl.parent,
     list.list_value,
     tbl.values_column,
     COALESCE (
         CASE
             WHEN list.list_value = 'Article' THEN tbl.values_column
         END,
         tbl2.values_column
     ) AS article,
     CASE
         WHEN list.list_value = 'Paragraph' THEN tbl.values_column
     END AS paragraph
 FROM
     pro_table tbl 
     LEFT JOIN list ON list.id_list = tbl.id_t_list
     LEFT JOIN pro_table tbl2 ON tbl2.id_pro_table = tbl.parent
```

... but that's making some assumptions about the hierarchy, so you probably need to tighten the join up based on the list type.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b97f9decb89a61e82bcdbcd15327ac5d) with invented relationships between the same six rows you showed, as we don't have the actual IDs.